# Need to make code efficient and reduce time complexity

Tags: c, time, time-complexity

Given a range [ L , R ] (both inclusive), I have to tell find the maximum difference between two prime numbers in the given range. There are three answers possible for the given range.

*If there is only one distinct prime number in the given range, then maximum difference in this case would be 0.*

*If there are no prime numbers in the given range, then output for this case would be -1.*

Example:

```
Range: [ 1, 10 ]

The maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range is 5.

Difference = 7 - 2 = 5


Range: [ 5, 5 ]

There is only one distinct prime number so the maximum difference would be 0.


Range: [ 8 , 10 ]

There is no prime number in the given range so the output for the given range would be -1.
```

Input Format
The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T

Next T lines each consists of two space-separated integers, L and R

Constraints
1<= T <=10

2<= L<= R<=10^6

This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int isprime(int n)
    {
        int i,c=0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
             c++;
        }
        if(c==1)
         return 1;
        else
         return 0;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int t; //testnumber
        scanf("%d",&t);
        for(int k=0;k<t;k++)
        {
         int l,r; //l=low or floor, r = highest range or ceiling;[l,r]
         scanf("%d%d",&l,&r);
         int n = r-l; //difference in range
         int a[n]; 
         int j=0;
         for(int i=l;i<=r;i++)
         {
             if(isprime(i)==1)
             {
                a[j] = i;
                j++;
             }
         }
         int d = a[j-1]-a[0];
         if(j==0)
          printf("%d\n",-1);
         else
          printf("%d\n",d);
        } 
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Making the code to run efficiently is actually *part of the task*. The first idea you come up with will often not be good enough to solve the problem, part of which is the time constraint. But just to say, your `isprime` loop needs only to test *odd* divisors, up the square root of `n`. And it can break the *first* time you find a factor. It does not need to complete the iteration. Another thing you might consider is to make a list of prime numbers so you don't have to keep repeating the same calculations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's so much for you to learn. Start by reading sieve of eratosthenes and then binary search the range in the array of prime numers.

Comment: start from isprime https://godbolt.org/z/hznbTcj5q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting on a forum/stack or asking for review, try to name your variables appropriately. Otherwise, it becomes uneasy to follow the code or what is the purpose of which variable.

I wrote the code below hoping you will understand my implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void isPrime(int num, int* primeNumber)
{
    if (num == 2)
    {
        *primeNumber = num; //2 is a prime number
        return;
    }
    if (num%2 == 0)
    {
        return; //num is an even number, so, not prime
    }
    int limit = sqrt(num);
    if (limit*limit == num)
    {
        return; //num is a square number, so, not prime
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i=i+2)//to find if a number is prime or not, we only have to divide it from 2 to sqrt(num).
    {          //i=i+2 skips even number, cause already checked if num is even or not.
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            return; //`num` is divisible by i, so, not prime
        }
    }
    *primeNumber = num; //no divisible number found. so, num is prime.
}

int main() 
{
    int testNumber;
    cout<< "Enter testNumber: ";
    cin>> testNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < testNumber; ++i)
    {
        int  newLow, low, high, lowestPrime = 0, highestPrime = -1;
        cin>> low>> high;
        newLow = low;
        if (low == high)
        {
            cout<<"0\n";
            continue;
        }

        for (int j = low; j <= high; ++j)//find the lowest prime
        {
            isPrime(j, &lowestPrime);
            if (lowestPrime != 0)//if lowest prime found, lowestprime will no longer be 0
            {
                //cout<<"lowest prime: "<<lowestPrime<<endl;
                newLow = j; //there is no prime number between low...newLow
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = high; j >= newLow; j--)//find highest prime
        {
            isPrime(j, &highestPrime);
            if (highestPrime != -1)//if highest prime found, highestprime will no longer be -1
            {
                //cout<<"highest prime: "<<highestPrime<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        cout<<highestPrime - lowestPrime<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't provide code for challenge problems: submit it directly on the site itself, as your own solution. There is a great deal written about prime number algorithms, which the OP could easily research. All you have done is to enable people to copy/paste and submit it as their own work, under the delusion that they have achieved something. It isn't even written in C as tagged.

Comment: I wanted him to just understand the implementation. He's newbie, so, I thought asking him to do research than answering the problem might scare him away from SO. That's why I concentrated on comments than language.

Answer (score 0):

This task doesn't require any special algorithm(except checking if number is prime in O(sqrt(N))) to be solved efficiently. Think about prime numbers, what is the frequency of them on some range (for example on range from 1 to 100) what is some "pattern" that appears. Now, if i understood the task correctly you need to find maximal difference of primes on range which is `last_prime_on_range - first_prime_on_range`, from this and previous observation you can easily devise an efficient algorithm.

Spoiler:

> You don't need to check whole range, it would be enough to check from L to L+100
>  and from R to R-100, obviously if L+100>R you can just go from L to R.
>  If you want to be sure you can go from L to L+1000 and from R to R-1000 since it  doesn't impact time complexity too much.
>  Also, adding a `break;` when you find a prime would also solve the problem.
>  Note that this gap between primes is not guaranteed to be bellow 100/1000 but for given range checking up to 1000 would be enough.

Now if you need to check all primes in range, you should learn about [Sieve Of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).